# How to pause the timer in c# for a while and then restart it

Tags: c#, timer

I'm using `System.Threading.Timer` timer object. I need to pause the timer inside the tick method so that I can do some stuff, and then restart the timer to start tick again.

```
    private  async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       timer1.Stop();
       timer1.Enabled = false;

         if (btn7)
         {
             timer.Stop();
         }
         fetch_hashtag();
         br2(); //posting in hashtages
         Console.WriteLine("waiting");
         while (timer1.Enabled == false)
         {
             Application.DoEvents();
             if (webBrowser2.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("blank"))
                 timer1.Enabled = true;
         }
         await Task.Delay((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(textBox4.Text)).TotalMilliseconds);
         timer1.Start();
    }

private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Stop();
    timer1.Tick -= timer1_Tick;

    // do some stuff

    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Consider using an `await Task.Delay()` loop instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but I'll tell you this much.  What you are doing is way more than what is needed, and in the case of `Enabled` and `Stop()`, it's just redundant.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Simply pass 0 for the constructor's *period* argument so you don't *have* to pause it.  Call Change() to get it to tick again.

Comment: when i execute the previous code the timer doesn't stop !!!

Comment: @NathanA, I believe the implied question which was added by the reviewer was accurate, but it doesn't constitute to making the question more clear. I'm voting to close anyways.

Comment: @rene The OP has posted his actual question in the comments, and it wasn't what the original editor assumed.  Either way, it's a mute point now IMHO.

Comment: @m1m6 souldn't you reverse the code? you stop before you start

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu no , i enabled the timer inside button click event ....

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pause the timer inside the tick method so that I can do some
>   stuff, and then restart the timer to start tick again.

The [Tick()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event is for `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, **not** `System.Threading.Timer`.  At any rate, just call [Stop()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx), do your "stuff", then call [Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx) again:

```
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();

    // do some stuff

    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Not working well, how?  Explain in more detail how it is not working, and more about the "stuff" you are doing...

Comment: i fetch trend hashtag from twitter then post a tweet in each hashtag
i need to do this each minute ,
what happened is : first fetch hashtags and start posting this process take more than one minute , so before it finished from posting in hashtags that i get first time ... the timer make a new request and fetch another hashtags before the previous process completed ...